# Update hidden form field with value from textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set the value of a hidden form field with the value entered in a textfield when submitting my form.

I have tried combining the answers to various questions but the closest I have come is getting the 'id' of my source field - but not the value.

Text field name = wpcf-available-stock
Hidden field name = wpcf-total-stock

The hidden field simply needs to be set to the same value as the text field on form submit using Jquery?

I cannot seem to find a simple sample in other questions asked... thanks

Comment: `$(HIDDEN).val($(INPUT).val())`.... Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why do you say, you need to set on submit ? Maybe you want to say, before submit and after the last input change it has to be set. Maybe it gets clearer this way ... JS is event based, everything happening can trigger something. I relax now and imagine what "combining" means in this delighting context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expeccted result, use below
HTML:

```
<input  type="hidden" name="wpcf-total-stock">
<input  type="text" name="wpcf-available-stock" value="test">
```

JS:

```
$("input[name='wpcf-available-stock']").on('keyup',function(){
$("input[name='wpcf-total-stock']").val($(this).val());
alert($("input[name='wpcf-total-stock']").val());
});
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/RRBwjA

Comment: I get an error 'Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function' when using any of the recommendations

Comment: I have jQuery included and am using jQuery for something different on the same form which works ok. I just tried adding this to my header but I received the same message:

`<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>`

Comment: Add as below <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>

Comment: The following code worked - it turned out not to be with loading jQuery but I needed to enclose in `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

});`

    I also removed the alert which caused a popup with every character entry. So this achieved what I was after:

    
`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("input[name='wpcf-available-stock']").on('keyup',function(){
$("input[name='wpcf-total-stock']").val($(this).val());
});
});`

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Why would you fill a hidden form field from a text field when you're going to send it anyway?

Second, the jQuery looks like this:

```
var fieldValue = $('#wpcf-available-stock').val();
$('#wpcf-total-stock').val(fieldValue);
```

You can obviously chain that together, but this is pretty clean.

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/u5Lj8cLz/

Comment: I am setting 2 fields to the same value when a user submits the form to save double entry (and as they will always initially be equal to 1 another).

I am receiving this error using the code provided:

Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: Well, you have to include jQuery (which I thought you would have, from your original post).
If you have them equal to each other initially anyway, you always could check if the hidden field is empty on the server - and then use the value from the ``available`` field.

Comment: I have jQuery included and am using jQuery for something different on the same form which works ok. I just tried adding this to my header but I received the same message:

`<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript solution.

```js
    updateHidden = function(x) {
      document.querySelector("[name=bar]").value = x;
    }
```

```html
    <input name="foo" value="" onchange="updateHidden(this.value)" type="text">
    <input name="bar" value="sometext" type="hidden">
```

**Update**

```js
updateHidden = function() {

document.querySelector("[name=bar]").value = document.querySelector("[name=foo]").value;
}


document.querySelector("[name=foo]").addEventListener("change", updateHidden);

/*
or, 
document.querySelector("[name=foo]").addEventListener("keyup", updateHidden);
*/
```

```html
        <input name="foo" type="text">
        <input name="bar" type="hidden">
```

Comment: The form fields are being generated using a Wordpress shortcode so I cannot use 'onchange'. I need to reference using the form id.